# Python comparing sets

Tags: python, set, compare

*I need to compare sets to see if one set is contained in another*

I am importing two text files as sets.

- `.txt` file 1: http://pastebin.com/P1t6eQV1
- `.txt` file 2: http://pastebin.com/eQn883Sp

from the `.txt` files you can see that the sets consist of the lines.

- `set1 = set(['thats true', 'thats false'])`
- `set2 = set(['Well done thats true', 'Unfortunately thats false'])`

**'thats false'** appears within the first index of set2 'Unfortunately **thats false**'. How do I print the index of where set1 is contained in set2?

Comment: It sounds like you not only want to check if one set is a subset of another, but if a string (an element of a set) is a substring of another string. Can you clarify?

Comment: You are testing for *substrings*; there is no strict intersection between your sets, and Python set objects don't support what you want out of the box. You'd either have to do N x M tests (create the product of the two sets and test each combination) or build an index of adjacent words to more efficiently do phrase searching. But that's too broad to discuss here on SO.

Comment: @T.Silver do sets contain strings? Sorry, if so you're correct. I want to search the entire of the second set to see if the first set is included anywhere within the second set.

Comment: So you want to check whether for each string `s` in `set1`, there is a string `ss` in `set2` such that `s` is a substring of `ss`. If that's correct, I would recommend editing the question.

Comment: If you mean the index of the item _in the set_, you can't do that because sets aren't ordered.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 I have changed them to lists so they are ordered

Answer (score 0):

The question should be changed to reflect the fact that order matters, so the values are lists, not sets. In this case, the code below should do the job

```
# returns True if l1 is a "substring sublist" of l2
def is_substring_sublist(l1, l2):
    next_idx1s = [0]
    target_idx = len(l1)
    for idx2 in range(len(l2)):
        idx1s = [x for x in next_idx1s]
        next_idx1s = [0]

        for idx1 in idx1s:
            if l1[idx1] in l2[idx2]:
                next_idx1s.append(idx1+1)

        if target_idx in next_idx1s:
            return True
    return False

# Unit tests
list1 = ['a', 'b']
list2 = ['b', 'a']
list3 = ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd']
list4 = ['a', 'a', 'b']

assert is_substring_sublist(list1, list1)
assert not is_substring_sublist(list1, list2)
assert is_substring_sublist(list1, list3)
assert is_substring_sublist(list1, list4)
assert not is_substring_sublist(list2, list4)
```